# Stetting up your Mac install phase is taking a long time; save to reboot?

Tags: imac, install, time

A friend of mine just got a new iMac from Best Buy. Installation phase went fine (I'm pretty sure OS came installed). She got to the "Setting up your Mac" phase and it's been stuck for about 3 hours right now. *Never* took this long before in dealing with Macs, ever.

Knowing potential problems with powering down during an install, I've been avoiding the turning-it-off-and-on-again option. Is it save to power down and reboot? I really don't know what OSX does during this step so I've been avoiding this possibility.

Today is Dec 26; Apple's servers might be overwhelmed with installs right now but I can't be certain since I've never purchased Macs anywhere except from Apple directly.

[FYI I have told her to contact Apple care and I suspect they might tell her to do something like that.]

I don't know the model iMac it is; she hasn't gotten back to me on our iMessage conversation. Once I know it I'll post it here. I'm pretty sure the computer is new since she got it from Best Buy; I at least know it's a clean HD.

Thx.
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing with my Non-retina MacBook Pro 13 back in August. I actually had to reboot several times because it hung up on me (after waiting several hours).

Nothing was harmed, the setup process should resume from where you left off.

Comment: Yeah my friend contacted AppleCare, restarting did it. Good thing to know in the future.